# Filter CSV files for specific value before importing

Tags: r

I have a folder with thousands of comma delimited CSV files, totaling dozens of GB.  Each file contains many records, which I'd like to separate and process separately based on the value in the first field (for example, aa, bb, cc, etc.).

Currently, I'm importing all the files into a dataframe and then subsetting in R into smaller, individual dataframes.  The problem is that this is very memory intensive - I'd like to filter the first column during the import process, not once all the data is in memory.

This is my current code:

```
setwd("E:/Data/")
files <- list.files(path = "E:/Data/",pattern = "*.csv")
temp <- lapply(files, fread, sep=",", fill=TRUE, integer64="numeric",header=FALSE)
DF <- rbindlist(temp)
DFaa <- subset(DF, V1 =="aa")
```

If possible, I'd like to move the "subset" process into lapply.

Thanks

Comment: You should reference the *package* which contains "fread" as it's not a base function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setwd("E:/Data/")
files <- list.files(path = "E:/Data/",pattern = "*.csv")
temp <- lapply(files, function(x) subset(fread(x, sep=",", fill=TRUE, integer64="numeric",header=FALSE), V1=="aa"))
DF <- rbindlist(temp)
```

Untested, but this will probably work - replace your function call with an anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks, this is great.

Comment: This will "help" in that the memory is freed after each file is processed.  If however a single file blows out RAM, it won't help.

Comment: Agreed, but that was the problem presented - each file is small enough, it's just that all combined they're too big. It's equally true that if the combined filtered list is too big, it won't help either, but it was assumed that this is not the case, given the problem presented.

Answer (score 3):

**1) read.csv.sql** This will read a file directly into a temporarily set up SQLite database (which it does for you) and then only read the `aa` records into R. The rest of the file will not be read into R at any time.   The table will then be deleted from the database.

`File` is a character string that contains the file name (or pathname if not in the current directory).  Other arguments may be needed depending on the format of the data.

```
library(sqldf)

read.csv.sql(File, "select * from file where V1 == 'aa'", dbname = tempfile())
```

**2) grep/findstr** Another possibility is to use grep (Linux) or findstr (Windows) to extract the lines with `aa`.  That should get you the desired lines plus possibly a few others and at that point you have a much smaller input so it could be subset it in R without memory problems.  For example,

```
fread("findstr aa File")[V1 == 'aa'] # Windows
fread("grep aa File")[V1 == 'aa']    # Linux
```

sed or gawk could also be used and are included with Linux and in [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) on Windows.

**3) external csv utilties** These external utilities understand csv and are free and available on all platforms that R supports: [csvfix](https://neilb.bitbucket.io/csvfix/), [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [csvtk](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/csvtk/), [miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and [xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv) (or the xsv fork [qsv](https://github.com/jqnatividad/qsv)).

We show examples using `fread` with csvfix or xsv

```
# csvfix
fread("csvfix find -if $1==aa File")  # Windows
fread("csvfix find -if '$1'==aa File")  # Linux bash

# xsv (qsv has same syntax)
fread("xsv search aa --select 1 File.csv File")[V1 == "aa"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help but you have to expand the function:

```
#Function
myload <- function(x) 
{
  y <- fread(x, sep=",", fill=TRUE, integer64="numeric",header=FALSE)
  y <- subset(y, V1 =="aa")
  return(y)
}
#Apply
temp <- lapply(files, myload)
```

Comment: This doesn't help, since you still have read the entire contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to muck with SQL,  consider using the `skip` argument in a loop. Slower, but that way you read in a block of lines, filter them, then read in the next block of lines (to the same temp variable so as not to take extra memory), etc.
Inside your `lapply` call, either a second `lapply` or equivalently

```
for (jj in 0: N) {
    foo <-  fread(filename, skip = (jj*1000+1):((jj+1)*1000), sep=",", fill=TRUE, integer64="numeric",header=FALSE)
    mydata[[jj]] <- do_something_to_filter(foo)
}
```